# Ocultando informações do banco no php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

***Código:***

```
foreach ($controller->ListaDados($objCheck) as $objCheck) { ?>
<table bordercolor="grey" border="1" class="container">
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="2" align="Center"><?php echo $objCheck->getemail(); ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Nesse `echo` está mostrando as seguintes informações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***String do banco:***

`Prezado Cliente <b><br><br>Pedido: <b>4264136</b>, NF: <b>1448692</b> <br>Pedido: <b>4264138</b>, NF: <b>1448693</b> <br>Pedido: <b>4264140</b>, NF: <b>1448694</b> <br><br>Data: <b>2015-12-08 10:37:49</b> Hora: <b>2015-12-08 10:37:49</b><br><br>Link do comprovante: <br><br><img src='cid:1krrpu5mb4br3'/>`

Tem algum jeito de mostrar somente os **Pedidos** e **NF** tratando isso no php e não no banco ? Por que isso é só o que me interessa.

Pois na coluna dentro do banco possui todas essas informações e não queria mexer nelas.

Comment: Coloque o restante do codigo, pois não como esta trazendo isso, se é numa consulta ou se é atraves de um foreach. E o que seria mostrar apenas pedidos e NF, seria apenas um registro, ou apenas esses campos da sua tabela?

Comment: Isso que to mostrando ai, é um campo, esse campo tem todas essas informações, queria saber se tem algum jeito de consultar esse campo e não me trazer tudo, só os pedidos e NF. Editei o código.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não consegui entender até agora como esta estruturado seu codigo/Banco, se por exemplo a data e o link estiverem no banco, vc deve imprimir no seu foreach o nome dos campos em cada tag TD

Comment: Mas não é cada campo, tudo isso acima vem de um campo só. Data, link pedido Nf tudo isso acima está em um campo só. Não está cada informação em um campo separado.

Comment: Então complicou, você ter que separar trechos de Strings e montar em uma tabela, seria preciso verificar como esta gravado na tabela e assim você criar algum metodo que pegue determinados trechos do codigo, utilizando um ponteiro pra definir onde comecar e onde parar de ler os dados da coluna.

Comment: Essa questão foi tratada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129381/filtro-consulta-sql.