# Filtro consulta SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, select

Possuo um campo chamado `emailMSG0` dentro de uma tabela no banco de dados. Nesse campo contém várias informações. Existe alguma possibilidade de no SQL eu filtrar o que eu quero pegar dentro desse campo `emailMSG0` ? Trazer só algumas informações.

Se eu fizer um select normal por exemplo:

```
SELECT emailMSG0 FROM TABELA
```

Me retorna isso:

`Prezado Cliente <b><br><br>Pedido: <b>4264136</b>, NF: <b>1448692</b> <br>Pedido: <b>4264138</b>, NF: <b>1448693</b> <br>Pedido: <b>4264140</b>, NF: <b>1448694</b> <br><br>Data: <b>2015-12-08 10:37:49</b> Hora: <b>2015-12-08 10:37:49</b><br><br>Link do comprovante: <br><br><img src='cid:1krrpu5mb4br3'/>`

Tem algum jeito de filtrar o que eu quero que apareça ?Tipo só quero que me retorne os pedidos desse campo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grosso modo no PHP seria mais ou menos isso que você iria fazer como o retorno do banco de dados

```
  <?php
        $retorno="Prezado Cliente <b></b><br><br>Pedido:<b>4544</b>NF:<b>4441</b>Pedido:<b>4543</b> NF:<b>4442</b>Pedido:<b>4546</b>NF:b>4443</b>Pedido:<b>4545</b>NF:<b>4444</b>Pedido:<b>4547</b>NF:<b>4445</b>";

        $teste = explode('Pedido:',strip_tags(explode('Data:', $retorno)[0], "<b></b><br>"));
        for($i =1; $i < sizeof($teste); $i++){
            $ped_nf = explode("NF:", $teste[$i]);
            echo ' Pedido: '. $ped_nf[0].' NF: '.$ped_nf[1];
        }
        //print_r($teste);
?>
```

É possível que seja necessário alguns ajustes, mas esse é um dos caminhos.

- É dado dois explodes na string para separar a parte dos pedidos e já retirando as tags HTML.
- Já começa a percorrer o array no índice 1, pois a posição 0 só ficou o nome do  Cliente.
- Depois outro explode para separar pedidos de NF e é vida que segue.
  Espero que ajude.

Comment: Cara, muito bom adaptei deu certo, porém após os pedidos tem mais informações como eu boto um fim nisso ? Setar uma posição para parar de percorrer o array. Logo após tem a informação data, parar quando chegar no data existe essa possibilidade ?

Comment: Coloca um exemplo da String ai para dar uma olhada, mas provavelmente esse resto será a ultima posição do array ai é só não pegar ela, se for isso no próprio for com sizeof() -1 já resolve.

Comment: Okay, vou editar minha pergunta com ela la.

Comment: Tá ajustado lá para não pegar depois  da data

Comment: Talvez essa sua resposta se encaixaria melhor nesta pergunta que fiz anteriormente a está.http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129211/ocultando-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-banco-no-php?noredirect=1#comment269239_129211

Comment: Beleza vou colocar lá também ai não sei como a moderação tratará isso;  Bom! eles sabem o que fazer. Isso ai, que bom que resolveu seu problema.

Answer (score 3):

Se você quer obter apenas parte do conteúdo de um campo que guarda XML, o ideal é utilizar uma aplicação externa ao SQL para tratar essa informação. Você pode fazer com SQL, mas não é a ferramenta mais adequada por vários motivos:

- SQL Server é pobre em API's para se trabalhar com XML;
- Mesmo que não fosse, a linguagem Transact-SQL é procedural. Qualquer código para lidar com XML fica provavelmente muito mais longo e complexo do que se você utilizasse uma linguagem orientada a objetos, por exemplo;
- Se você está guardando XML com um schema bem definido no banco de dados, talvez você deva repensar sua aplicação para transformar os dados do XML em outro formato mais normalizado para guardar no banco.

Se ainda assim você quiser seguir adiante, você pode usar [XQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms191474(v=sql.120).aspx). É suportado a partir do SQL Server 2008. O link aí é a documentação oficial, traduzida por máquina pra PT-br. Sugiro dar uma olhada na documentação em inglês se você for fluente.

Comment: Não é bem XML, só queria pegar algo especifico desse campo para não ter que mexer na estrutura do banco pois vou utilizar essas informações em uma aplicação web.

Comment: Não conheço seu contexto, mas mesmo sem olhar eu apostaria um PS4 que seguir por esse caminho só vai tornar seu trabalho mais difícil a médio e longo prazo.

Comment: Aquilo não é xml, é html.

Comment: Eu não mexo no banco só na aplicação web mas para fazer a consulta preciso filtrar isso ai, e o mais fácil creio eu seria tratar no sql que faz a consulta.

Comment: Acho que teve uma pergunta parecida com essa ontem http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129211/ocultando-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-banco-no-php
E acredito que pra extrair determinados trechos da string vai ter que tratar isso no PHP, encontrando uma logica pra implementar em algum metodo

Comment: E pelo o que eu entendi, você quer tirar as informacoes de numero de pedido e numero de nota fiscal, de um campo onde guarda a mensagem de email com todos esses dados e mais algumas outras informações

Comment: Tentei achar em PHP mas na consulta SQL acho que seria mais eficaz, o trabalho no php dobra para fazer isso.

Comment: Cara acredito que tratar isso no PHP seria menos custoso para você, visto que na consulta você teria de usar um monte de locates e substrings para fazer isso e não teria um resultado estável, acredito que na aplicação seria mais fácil de tratar isso.

Comment: Tem o substring_index também, mas você não tem  um numero fixo de pedidos naquele campo, não é? E mesmo assim ainda ia ser custoso isso.

Comment: É os número não são fixos, o certo seria criar uma coluna com pedidos uma com as NF porém não posso mexer na estrutura, vou ter que achar algo na aplicação mesmo. Tem alguma solução ?

Comment: Cara uma das soluções possíveis seria você pegar a string que retornada do banco e dar um explode('Pedidos:', $retorno); a partir do índice 1 do array você já terá somente os números de pedidos e nfs, mas isso é só o primeiro passo ai você terá que tratar melhor isso, mas já é um caminho

Comment: Respondi ali, é mais ou menos aquilo que tem que ser feito com o retorno do banco de dados